# How can I solve the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2" problem?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code. I think the problem ir related to the environment of the code.

Im trying to import the psycopg2 pool method (`from psycopg2 import pool`) after installing it with `pip install psycopg2`, and it says that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+shift+p`, type `Python: Select Interpreter` and choose the correct environment if it is an environment issue.

Comment: Thanks man, it works now. Can you explain to me why is that?

Comment: Great!. So basically, VS Code was executing the program using the default Python of the system, and you are installing the package in another python such as conda or any venv or conda env. So you need to make sure VScode runs the program using that env. Can you upvote and mark it tick if it is solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The packages installed in the python environment you have selected can work.

You can through `pip show psycopg2` to know where have you installed the psycopg2.To know which python interpreter you have selected from the bottom-left on the VSCode.

And after you switch the python interpreter, remember to renew a terminal(shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+`**), the python extension will activate this python environment in the terminal, then the packages can be installed in the right place.